# Stripe PaymentIntent test class Java Springs

Tags: java, mockito, stripe-payments

I am trying to add few test classes to for code coverage for Stripe payment Integration.I am not able to Mock PaymentIntent or RequestOptions.

Method

```
@Override
public String createPaymentIntent() {

    List<Object> paymentMethodTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    paymentMethodTypes.add("card");
    final CartModel cartModel = cartService.getSessionCart();
    final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    final double totalPrice = 100 * 100;
    params.put("amount", Double.valueOf(totalPrice).longValue());
    params.put("currency",USD);
    params.put("payment_method_types", paymentMethodTypes);
    try {
        RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setApiKey(getSecretApiKey()).build();
        PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.create(params, requestOptions);
        return paymentIntent.getId();
    } catch (final StripeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Test Method

```
try (MockedStatic<PaymentIntent> paymentIntentMock = mockStatic(PaymentIntent.class);
            MockedStatic<RequestOptions> requestOptionsMock = mockStatic(RequestOptions.class)) {
                private RequestOptions.RequestOptionsBuilder requestOptionsBuilder = RequestOptions.builder();
        requestOptionsMock.when(()->RequestOptions.builder()).thenReturn(requestOptionsBuilder);
        requestOptionsBuilder.setApiKey("secretkey");
        given(requestOptionsBuilder.build()).willReturn(requestOptions);
        paymentIntentMock.when(()->PaymentIntent.create(anyMap(),requestOptions)).thenReturn(paymentIntent);
        given(paymentIntent.getId()).willReturn("paymentId");
        assertEquals(tripePaymentService.createPaymentIntent(), "paymentId");
    }
```

When I run the test Method I am getting the following ERROR:

```
java.lang.InternalError: class redefinition failed: invalid class

at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
```

Thanks, InAdvance.

Comment: You cannot `builder()`, `setApiKey()` and `build()` in one "when" ...these are three methods...of different classes/objects

Comment: xerx593  Thanks for the quick response. I modified the above above test method with respect to you instructions. Still the same error .It's showing error at  mockStatic(PaymentIntent.class)